# RubyGems Installation - getting  ruby: No such file or directory -- setup.rb (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I run

```
gem install rubygems-update
```

but I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
    HTTP Response 302 fetching http://gems.rubyforge.org/yaml
```

My environemnt is:

```
~$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.1.0 (1.1.0)
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]
  ...
```

When I run:

```
$ ruby setup.rb
```

I get:

```
ruby: No such file or directory -- setup.rb (LoadError)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 7):

First you need to successfully Installed Ruby. execute below command on console

```
ruby -v
```

If you get version of ruby then go ahead and [download rubygems](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126) and extract the folder.
Suppose you download rubygems-1.8.17.tgz and extracted in /home/amit/rubygems1.8.17

```
cd /home/amit/rubygems1.8.17
ruby setup.rb
```

after successfully installed, do `gem -v` it should display gem version

If your RubyGems version is 0.8.5 or later, you can upgrade to the latest version with:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

If your current version of RubyGems is older than version 0.8.5, or specifically RubyGems 1.2.0, or you see the message “Nothing to update” when you tried gem update —system, then use the following commands:

```
gem install rubygems-update

update_rubygems
```

if your system requires root access to install ruby libraries, use sudo

Comment: please help me uninstall ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-02) [i486-linux]

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your rubygems:

```
gem install rubygems-update --source http://production.s3.rubygems.org/
update_rubygems
```

If that doesn't work, this post:

[Can't update RubyGems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954206/cant-update-rubygems) may help.

Comment: ~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-02) [i486-linux]
how to uninstall it??

Answer (score 0):

Check do you have setup.rb file or not. If you do have one then try to go into that  where your file is located and the execute

> ruby setup.rb

Comment: and if you do not have it?